# How do I get vimperator to ignore a site such as gmail

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, gmail, vimperator

vimperator is great for navigating the web in general form the keyboard, though some pages like gmail have domain specific keys that are better for that specific task.

For instance in gmail <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> move to the next and previous messages. When I have vimperator these are captured and scroll the page instead. I would like to tell vimperator to ignore mail.google.com entirely (unless there is a more elegant solution of course)

I have looked at Pentadactyl as an alternative that is rumored to have this feature though it seems to not run on firefox 35+ (at least at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

I found some clues on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271624/disable-vimperator-temporarily) and came up with this ~/.vimeratorrc :

```
source! /home/arthur/.vimperatorrc.local

autocmd LocationChange .*                             js modes.passAllKeys = false
autocmd LocationChange mail\\.google\\.com            js modes.passAllKeys = true
autocmd LocationChange www\\.google\\.com/calendar    js modes.passAllKeys = true
```

" vim: set ft=vimperator: